# Node js chat bot issue: session.error()

Tags: node.js, chatbot

I have written a dummy bot using the latest botbuilder version : 3.4.4. My sample code is:

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(config.port,config.ip,function () {
try{
console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
console.log("Welcome to Banker Bot!!!!");
}
catch(err){
console.log("Server already in Use" + err);
}

});
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
appId: config.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
appPassword: config.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD

});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.model);
bot.dialog('/', [
function (session) {
session.beginDialog('/askName');
},
function (session, results) {
session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);
}
]);
bot.dialog('/askName', [
function (session) {
builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
},
function (session, results) {
session.endDialogWithResult(results);
}
]);
```

I am trying to talk to my bot using emulator. I am able to connect to bot as I get : "ChatConnector: Message Received" when I type anything, then I get a session.error(). Please guide me as to where I am going wrong. I am completely novice to chatbot and nodejs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling results.response in `session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);` but here when I have run code results is undefined hence it goes in session.err dialog.